# bash like --init-file in the tcsh

Tags: gnu-screen, tcsh

The `bash/screen` scenario:

```
screen -dmS sessionname -c /path/to/screenrc
```

the `/path/to/screenrc` contains for example

```
screen -t windowtitle1 bash --init-file /path/to/window1.bashinit
screen -t windowtitle2 bash --init-file /path/to/window2.bashinit
screen -t windowtitle3 bash --init-file /path/to/window3.bashinit
```

e.g. it

- starts a `screen` session in detached mode
- the `screen` execute the defined `screenrc`
- from the `screenrc`

  - starts 3 different interactive `bash` windows
  - and each the bash executes the content of the defined `init-file`
  - and after executing them, the `bash` continue in interactive mode (!)

So, at the end I got

- an detached `screen` session
- with a 3x running `bash` in interactive mode
- and each of them already executed some commands (defined in their `init-file`)

How to achieve the same functionality with the `tcsh`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to force `tcsh` to do the work that `screen` can do for you instead.
Simply start your 3 windows:

```
cat <<\! >/path/to/screenrc
screen -t windowtitle1 tcsh
screen -t windowtitle2 tcsh
screen -t windowtitle3 tcsh
!
screen -dmS sessionname -c /path/to/screenrc
```

then stuff (ie "type") the init command into each window:

```
screen -p windowtitle1 -X stuff 'source /path/to/window1.tcshinit\n'
screen -p windowtitle2 -X stuff 'source /path/to/window2.tcshinit\n'
screen -p windowtitle3 -X stuff 'source /path/to/window3.tcshinit\n'
```

Comment: This is great. Just instead of the `\n` i must use ^M (`CTRL-V` `CTRL-M`), otherwise i just got in the window: `source /path/to/window1.tcshinit\n` (with the literal `\n`) and the `source` command isn't executed.

Comment: ok, good to know. I tried `\n` and `\r` and they both seemed to work. I'm not sure why they don't for you, perhaps different versions of the tools.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't, not directly anyway.

What you can do is create `win1.tcsh`, `win2.tcsh`, etc. with the contents:

```
echo Starting win1
setenv WINDOW 1
exec tcsh
```

Invoke that as `tcsh -c 'source  win1.tcsh'`, and in your `tcshrc` do something like:

```
if ( $WINDOW == "1" ); then
   # My custom commands...
endif
```